# Pure virtual method must be implemented only in immediate derived classes - why?

Tags: c++, class, derived-class, pure-virtual

Suppose there is an abstract class `A` and two classes `B` & `C` derived from `A` and `B` respectively

```
class A
{
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
    void print(); 
};

//print() must be implemented
void B::print()
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

class C : public B
{
    //print() does not require to be implemented
};
```

I understand that from `C`'s perspective of its immediate parent `B`, print() is not a pure virtual method, but from `C`'s perspective of its grandparent `A`, print() is a pure virtual method. So, shouldn't it require implementation in `C` too?

Comment: Why should `C` care how `B` provides all its goodies? And pure virtual functions need not be implemented in derived classes. They just need to be implemented somewhere for a derived class not to have a pure virtual function, and thus being non-instantiable.

Comment: C inherits its implementation from B so it doesn't have to provide one. However, B does not get one from A because it's pure virtual.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by these two "perspectives". The function has a non-pure override, so all is good. It doesn't matter exactly where that override is in the hierarchy, as long as it exists.

Comment: @Borgleader: `B` *could* get one from `A`, even though `A` marks the function pure-virtual. That's most common with dtors though...

Comment: @Deduplicator I was referring to this specific case. And in this case, it does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C` doesn't "care" how it gets an implementation, just that it gets one.  And it gets one from `B`.  However `B` receives no implementation of `print` and therefore needs to implement `print` on its own

**EDIT**: Per comments below, the implementation must not be marked as pure virtual again

Comment: Just getting an implementation is not enough. The implementer must not mark it pure-virtual (*again*).

Comment: @Deduplicator you can't provide an implementation for a pure virtual, it is enough to state you provided an implementation, the fact it's not pure virtual can be implied, so sedavidw's statement is complete and non-reduntant, and you are just nitpicking

Comment: @Zadirion: "You can't provide an implementation for a pure virtual..."? Just try it, it works wonderfully.

Comment: @Deduplicator Edited the question appropriately

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a definition for everything which is ODR-used, and virtual functions are always ODR-used by the class (vtable).

Unless, of course, they are marked pure virtual.

A class is abstract, and thus cannot be instantiated, iff it has at least one pure virtual member.
It does not matter whether that member is inherited or not, but inheritance is only directly from the base-classes.

Being pure-virtual does not foreclose actually being defined, allowing for non-virtual invocation.